# About the PHP require_once

Tags: php, require-once

I recently came across this piece of weird functionality:

`index.php`:

```
<?php
  require_once("include/header.php");
?>
```

`include/header.php`:

```
<?php
  require_once("./config.inc.php");
  require_once("./func.inc.php");
?>
fooo!
```

`include/config.inc.php` and `include/func.inc.php` are empty.

When I try loading `index.php`, it gives me a white page, with nothing.

But when I change `include/header.php` to this:

```
<?php
  require_once("config.inc.php"); // notice the loss of ./
  require_once("func.inc.php");
?>
fooo!
```

It suddenly works.

I have previously used `./` before file names in PHP web applications before, and it didn't seem to break, so I was a bit bewildered by this functionality.

Why does it occur?

Thanks!

Comment: *Blank Page* ? Make sure php errors are on in your script.

Comment: Use this `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top and see, do you get any error if you use `./`

Comment: ./ means current folder, and it should't give any problem. try error reporting